# C file read by line up to a custom delimiter

Tags: c, file, delimiter

Is there a function in C to read a file with a custom delimiter like '\n'?

For example: I have:

I did write \n to exemplify in the file is the LF (Line feed, '\n', 0x0A)

```
this is the firstline\n this is the second line\n
```

I'd like the file to read by part and split it in two strings:

```
this is the firstline\n
this is the second line\n
```

I know fgets I can read up to a num of characters but not by any pattern. In C++ I know there is a method but in C how to do it?

I'll show another example:

I'm reading a file ABC.txt

```
abc\n
def\n
ghi\n
```

With the following code:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("ABC.txt", "rt");
const int lineSz = 300;
char line[lineSz];
char* res = fgets(line, lineSz, fp); // the res is filled with abc\ndef\nghi\n
fclose(fp);
```

I excpected fgets had to stop on abc\n

But the res is filled with: abc\ndef\nghi\n

> **SOLVED:** The problem is that I was using Notepad++ in WindowsXP (the one I used
>   I don't know it happens on other windows) saved the file with different
>   encoding.
>
> The newline on fgets needs the CRLF not just the CR when you type
>   enter in notepad++
>
> I opened the windows notepad And it worked the fgets reads the string
>   up to abc\n on the second example.

Comment: By `\n`, do you mean an actual newline, or the characters backslash and n? It's not standard C, but POSIX 2008 has the GNU `getdelim` function that might do what you want.

Comment: `fgets` reads exactly a line, to the first `\n` character. Its only limitation is the size of reserved buffer.

Comment: are you sure? I did a program it read the \n of the text, I'll check it again.

Comment: @okami: Would you mind providing another example without C-escape-like sequences? Just use normal text. That would make your question a LOT clearer.

Comment: yes it is written in the buffer with fgets :-/

Comment: The 't' in the `fopen` mode string is **undefined Behavior**. The usual string to open in text mode is "r"; if your implementation defines "rt" as 'open in text mode', just ignore your implementation documentation and use plain "r"; otherwise (if the 't' means something strange) you're pretty much locked to using your implementation

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` will read one line at a time, and does include the newline character in the line output buffer.  Here's an example of the common usage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    while ( fgets(buf,1024,stdin) )
        printf("read a line %lu characters long:\n  %s", strlen(buf), buf);
    return 0;
}
```

But since you asked about using a "custom" delimiter... `getdelim()` allows you to specify a different end-of-line delimiter.

Comment: No I didn't asked any custom delimiter.
If I have less than 1024 (on your example) and I have a newline character on the position 200 will the buffer be filled with characters up to this newline character?

Comment: @okami yes. if the actual question is "How to get rid of it" then try `buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0'` . You may also need to check if the string actually contain it.

Comment: ruslik It's not what is happening with me, look at my second example (I edited the question).

Comment: @okami AHA! What you don't understand is that '\n' actually means "new line character" (with ASCII code 0xA or 0xD), and not the sequence of two characters: \ and n .

Comment: Ruslik I know newline It is '\n', I'm sure in the file is the newline one CR I pressed enter not typed \n on the file writting

Comment: @okami are you using Notepad++ in windows by any chance? It sometimes saves text files in Machintosh encoding, creating problems with newlines.

Comment: @okami \n, \r and lots of other \somethings have special significance in C. If you printf("Hello world\n"); you will just see Hello world and a newline i.e. the next piece of output will be on the line below. You will NOT see the \n characters as they are in the printf string because they will have been converted. Now, fgets will stop at a newline character - the one that printf printed with "\n" and the one you normally get in a file by pressin enter/return in an editor. It will NOT stop if you edit your file and add the text '\n' somewhere.

Comment: Yes I'm using notepad++ in windows... I'll find the encoding of it.